# pass pillar to reactor from a state

Tags: salt-stack

I have one orchestrator which applying some stuff on a bunch of minions.
Also, have a reactor that is listening for a certain event to be returned from a state, "- fire_event: my custom tag".
What I need is somehow to pass pillar data to the reactor from the state, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method would be to include the pillar data in the event you are sending. If you are using `event.send` state to send the event, you can include `with_pillar: true` in the state, to include all pillar data. If you don't want to include all pillars, you can use jinja to render the pillars you do want into the data section.

```
event sending:
  event.send:
    - name: event/tag/like/normal
    - data:
        item1: {{salt["pillar.get"]('thing1')}}
        item2: {{salt["pillar.get"]('etc')}}
```

Things in data will be included in the event that gets to the reactor.